# Верхняя плашка c менюхой, поиском и индикаторами больше не закрепляется сверху страницы, а исчезает при скролле

Tags: обсуждение, дефект

Собственно, вопрос. Такое поведение плашки эксклюзивно у меня или у всех? В верстке вроде все нормально `{ position: fixed; top: 0; }`. Может быть, заменить `fixed` на `sticky`?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что это моя ошибка. Плашка не закрепляется сверху из-за использования кастомного стиля. Проблема имеет единичный характер.

Comment: Нормальный вопрос с хорошим ответом, зря закрыли

Comment: @vp_arth только вот ответ на несколько другой вопрос. Если я правильно понял, у ТС опции из ответа настроены правильно, но проблема в кастомном стиле. Т.е. если хочется оставить "хороший ответ" надо подправить (по сути изменив вовсе) вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого есть настройка в профиле.

1. Перейдите в свой профиль.
2. Нажмите на вкладку «Настройки».
3. Снимите галочку в пункте «Отключить фиксацию верхней панели навигации»

[image: Настройка]

После этого верхняя плашка должна прилипнуть.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Про ту опцию не знал. Галочки там не стояло. Но я смог выяснить причину, и, похоже, она индивидуальная. Причиной стала некачественная таблица стилей с сайта userstyles.org. Очень обидно, что там нет актуальных рабочих стилей.

Comment: @DiD Ну, все хорошо что хорошо кончается :) А что за скрит/стиль? Возможно на главное мете или stackapps есть альтернативы.

Comment: Да вот очень странно, вроде в сообществе так много толковых веб-мастеров, а на userstyles.org из рабочих два с половиной стиля и те уже устарели. Пыталось найти темную тему для сайта. Но, всё что есть - версии прошлых лет, что безнадежно наполовину не работает.

Comment: В итоге остановилось на правилах, добавленных Dark Reader + добавилось 4 своих правила CSS: `html { background: #000; }
body { filter: hue-rotate(180deg); }
img { filter: hue-rotate(180deg); opacity: .5; }
img:hover { opacity: 1; }` Вот так уже выглядит неплохо. Правда, осталось восстановить зелёный цвет до зелёного.

Comment: Скриншот выложен https://imgur.com/a/jJ6NYdo

Comment: @DiD Пробовали вариант на gihub: [StackOverflow-Dark](https://github.com/StylishThemes/StackOverflow-Dark) ? Выглядит так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Id8ng.png

Comment: Тема вылитая как у Dark reader. Похоже я ее и использую, только развернув оттенки цветов на 180º. Просто мне не нравится голубой цвет элементов, Рыжий куда теплее и уютнее. А вот зелёные элементы надо восстановить. Кстати, я не знаю автора темы, возможно, тему разрабатывали сами авторы SO, уж больно гиганская получилась. - 200кб. При том, что у DarkReader та же тема вышла в 4 строчки CSS  плюс мои 4 строчки, то есть максимум - 1.5кб.